# Colon in echo batch command

Tags: batch-file

What does this command, found in a script, mean ?

`echo run cmake build: %Some_Directory%\CMake\build.bat`

`cmake` does have a `build` argument, but there should be hyphens :
`cmake --build`

Here is the **echo** documentation :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490897(v=technet.10)

And an other documentation I found :
https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html

The last one mentions the colon character, but located just after the echo command.
The Microsoft's documentation doesn't mention it at all.

My knowledge  of the batch language is very limited...

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo` displays text, and so that command just displays the string `run cmake build: %Some_Directory%\CMake\build.bat`, and `%Some_Directory%` will be replaced by its actual value.

Nothing after the `echo` command gets executed (except in cases where there's an unescaped `&`, `|`, or `>`).

Comment: Thanks ! And sorry for this stupid question. :)

Comment: It's not a stupid question; the syntax is weird compared to literally all other languages where the command to display text wraps the string in quotes.